# Give different color to each stack in stacked line combo chart in anychart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, anychart

I have designed a stacked column chart I just wanted to change the different colors of each stack I have used a stacked-line combo chart from any chart It uses the default color I have to change each stack color how should I change color even I use color().[![enter image description here][1]][1]fill it is not working properly.

```
let dataSet = anychart.data.set([
  ["1", 96.5, 2040, 1200, 1600],
  ["2", 77.1, 1794, 1124, 1724],
  ["3", 73.2, 2026, 1006, 1806],
  ["4", 61.1, 2341, 921, 1621],
  ["5", 70.0, 1800, 1500, 1700],
  ["6", 60.7, 1507, 1007, 1907],
  ["7", 62.1, 2701, 921, 1821],
  ["8", 75.1, 1671, 971, 1671],
  ["9", 80.0, 1980, 1080, 1880],
  ["10", 54.1, 1041, 1041, 1641],
  ["11", 51.3, 813, 1113, 1913],
  ["12", 59.1, 691, 1091, 1691],
  ["1", 96.5, 2040, 1200, 1600],
  ["2", 77.1, 1794, 1124, 1724],
  ["3", 73.2, 2026, 1006, 1806],
  ["4", 61.1, 2341, 921, 1621],
  ["5", 70.0, 1800, 1500, 1700],
  ["6", 60.7, 1507, 1007, 1907],
  ["7", 62.1, 2701, 921, 1821],
]);

let firstSeriesData = dataSet.mapAs({ x: 0, value: 1 });

let secondSeriesData = dataSet.mapAs({ x: 0, value: 2 });

let thirdSeriesData = dataSet.mapAs({ x: 0, value: 3 });

let fourthSeriesData = dataSet.mapAs({ x: 0, value: 4 });

let chart = anychart.column();

chart.animation(true);

chart.title("Combination of Stacked Column and Line Chart (Dual Y-Axis)");

let setupSeriesLabels = function (series, name) {
  series.name(name).stroke("3 #fff 1");
  series.hovered().stroke("3 #fff 1");
};
var series;

chart.yScale().stackMode("value");
chart.yScale().stackDirection("direct");

let scale = anychart.scales.linear();
scale.minimum(0).maximum(100).ticks({ interval: 5 });

let extraYAxis = chart.yAxis(1);
extraYAxis.orientation("right").scale(scale);
extraYAxis.labels().padding(0, 0, 0, 5);

extraYAxis.labels().format("{%Value}");

series = chart.column(secondSeriesData);
setupSeriesLabels(series, "To-Do");

chart.crosshair(true);

let lineSeries = chart.line(
  firstSeriesData,
  setupSeriesLabels(series, "Remaining Task"),
  "#3ba158"
);
lineSeries.yScale(scale).markers(true);

series = chart.column(thirdSeriesData);
setupSeriesLabels(series, "Requirements Complete");

series = chart.column(fourthSeriesData);
setupSeriesLabels(series, "Estimated Minutes");

chart.legend().enabled(true).fontSize(13).padding([0, 0, 20, 0]);

chart.yAxis().labels().format("{%index}{groupsSeparator: \\,}");

chart.xAxis(0).title("Sprint Days");

chart.yAxis().title("Number of Tasks");
chart.yAxis(1).title("Total Hours");

chart.interactivity().hoverMode("by-x");

chart.tooltip().valuePrefix("$").displayMode("union");

chart.xGrid().enabled(true);
chart.yGrid().enabled(true);

chart.xMinorGrid().enabled(true);
chart.yMinorGrid().enabled(true);
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understood you well. In stacked charts, different series have different colors. It means that the stack includes several points with different colors. It is required to distinguish series in the stack. Do you want to color the whole stack with the same color? Can you provide an example of the desired coloring?

Comment: Yes, you are right different series have different colors but I want to change the stack color it is showing the default color I want to change the colors of each series how to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that using `fill()` method of the series instance. Like this:

```
  var series = chart.column(secondSeriesData);
  series.fill('purple');
```

For details, check [the sample based on your snippet](https://playground.anychart.com/ucDxg2Gn) and pay attention to lines 58, 71 and 75.